# How to build EF7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I just cloned EF7 code from GitHub, opened the solution, and a lot of errors were identified, mostly classes/interfaces not found. I though that maybe it was because of some dlls missing but that was not the case. No references had the typical warning sign on the lower left, but still a lot of code was just not accounted for... Important interfaces such as ILogger and others.

So, what did I do wrong? Am I forgetting something? Do I need to download/install other packs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0: Install Visual Studio 2015 (for example the free Community edition)

1: Clone repo

```
git clone https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.git
```

2: Run:

```
build initialize
```

Instructions available here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Getting-and-Building-the-Code

Comment: thank you very much! worked as expected after I restarted VS... errors went away only after that...